# raw_input() not waiting for user input

Tags: python

I'm facing an odd problem with `raw_input`. It doesn't appear to be waiting for users input. Here is the method that's failing:

```
def displayCaptcha(self):
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=xxxxxxxx'

    r = requests.get(url)
    m = re.search("challenge : '(.+)'", r.text)

    if not m:
        raise Exception('Could not fetch ReCaptcha challange code')

    c = m.groups(0)

    # Fetch the captcha image from Google's servers
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=%s" % c)
    Image.open(StringIO(r.content)).show()
    captchaResponse = raw_input('Enter Captcha: ')

    # Problem!
    print 'This prints even before user has entered any key'

    return c, captchaResponse
```

Output:

```
God@War:$ echo "190106193" | ./liker.py username password
Enter Captcha: This prints even before user has entered any key
Login failed. Exiting ...
```

What's odd is it was working fine. I write the code, and now its stumped me. But, from what I can see the `print` after `raw_input` shouldn't be printing until the user has entered a key, so it looks like my problem is here.

Any ideas?

Which calls ...

```
try:
    r = self.login()
except CaptchaError:
    # Login failed site requesting captcha
    r = self.loginWithCaptcha()

# If login wasn't successful, return
if not r:
    return False

# Login is successful, set login status to True, fetch
# the users OAuth token
self.loggedIn = True
self.token = self.getOauthToken()

# Save the session to disk so the user hasn't got to
# login each time.
self.saveSession()

return True
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7.3 but it was working yesterday

Comment: So just to clarify, it was working yesterday and no changes have been made since?

Comment: Changes to a class method was made, but not to this method. I will paste the code that calls this method.

Comment: Maybe there remains a newline character in the buffer. Try `sys.stdin.flush()` before you call `raw_input`.

Comment: Ah, there IS a newline in the buffer

Comment: Although it didnt solve the problem

Comment: Are you working on Windows? `sys.stdin.flush()` does not work on Windows but there are ways to do it, google might know the answer.

Comment: So it didn't work for me either (on some RedHat derivative) but this helped: `import termios` and `termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)` before the `raw_input`. You can test whether discarding the buffer is successful on your OS with a small script in which you call `time.sleep` before `raw_input` and then you enter characters while the program is sleeping. If the `stdin` is flushed correctly they should not appear on the `raw_input`.

Comment: @a_guest I'm running Debian Wheezy. Will try your last suggestion